# React Native Xcode build error when building duplicated target

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a react native ios project where I have two different Targets of the app. The original target builds and archives just fine, but the duplicated and renamed target does not.

I get `Lexical or Preprocessor` issues and `React/RCTxxx.h file not found` errors when buildnig or archivning.

I have created a new target in the Podfile as well and I can see in the duplicated targets Linked frameworks and Libraries section that it includes all the React libraries and the pod framework.

I can't understand why it's not working to build the duplicated target. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of 2 options:

**1.** Try to remove the rename target. And re-duplicate the original then retry.

**2.** If the error still happens. Try to remove the React from Pod.

- In ios/Podfile: Comment out some package link looks like: #pod 'react-native-fcm', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fcm'
- Manual link these packages commenting out above.

**Note:** You should keep only React Xcode libraries link or Pod. But there're some problem with the cocoapods 1.4.0 and React Native 0.5x.x